# MySQL : getting records based on a column's value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have `n` records in `my_table`.

I want to select all the records from the table, so I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table`;
```

I then limit it with a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE id > 30;
```

But there is a column (`cat_name`) in `my_table` whose value is decisive. This column's value is not unique, and hence there might be many repetitions in the records. I want to limit the records so that each value of `cat_name`'s value **MUST NOT** be repeated more than four times, hence, I want such result:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id | name       | cat_name
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
33 + Robert     +  Radio 
34 + Alice      +  Radio 
35 + Jennifer   +  Radio 
36 + Sara       +  Radio 
37 + Maria      +  TV 
38 + Sebastian  +  TV 
38 + Jack       +  TV 
40 + Albert     +  TV
.
.
... the rest of records
```

but **UNFORTUNATELY** I am getting this result because I do not how should I 
limit the query in such specific way:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id | name       | cat_name
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
33 + Robert     +  Radio
34 + Alice      +  TV
35 + Jennifer   +  Radio
36 + Sara       +  Radio
36 + Maria      +  Radio
36 + Sebastian  +  TV
36 + Jack       +  Radio
36 + Albert     +  Radio
...
```

Comment: If `'Alice'` is related to `'Radio'` in your table then how can you possibly get a result where `'Alice'` is related to `'TV'`?

Comment: Well, this is an example data, you are going far from the question, I'm saying concentrate on the repetition of `cat_name`, I don't want the records' `cat_name` value to be repeated more than four times

Comment: For relatively small dataset `COUNT()` and `HAVING` clause may do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I would address this problem by enumerating the rows for each `cat_name` and then choosing the first four:

```
select ci.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = cat_name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := cat_name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from my_table t cross join
           (select @c := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by cat_name, id
     ) ci
where rn <= 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE id > 30 ORDER BY cat_name DESC

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

**edit:** sorry, read too quickly.
if you want to limit the amount of rows within each group of 'cat_name' - i don't think there's an easy way with mySQL.

with postgreSQL you could select     row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "cat_name") and filter by that, but i don't know if there is an equivalent in mySQL.

So I would recommend letting PHP filter the data:

```
<?php
[...]
$resultarray = [];
$lastgroup = "";
$count = 0;
while($row = $mysqli_fetch_assoc()) {
  if($row['cat_name'] != $lastgroup) {
    $lastgroup = $row['cat_name'];
    $count = 0;
  }
  $count++;
  if($count <= 4) {
    $resultarray[] = $row;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the answer to my question